# Throwable = Malformed URL. Base: https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/, Relative: speech:longrunningrecognize

Tags: android, speech-recognition, retrofit2, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm testing requests on Android use Retrofit2 and I get this throwable.

```
URL_BASE = "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/";
```

My request

```
@POST("speech:longrunningrecognize")
    Call<String> longRecognize(@Query("key") String key,
                               @Body LongRunningRecognize loginResponse);
```

And when clicked

```
btnInitialSpeech.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            RestClient.INSTANCE.getApiServiceInterface()
                    .longRecognize(GOOGLE_API_KEY, getLongRecognize(f.getName()))
                    .enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                                String body = String.valueOf(response.body());
                                Log.d(TAG, "Response = " + body);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Throwable = " + t.getMessage());

                        }
                    });
        });
```

I created project and doing all like here https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/async-recognize
Please, tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.

Here `speech:longrunningrecognize` instead ":" need "/".